# Use TreeView hierarchy with HierarchicalDataTemplate from inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a WPF application which uses a `TreeView`, inside that `TreeView` there are multiple `HierarchicalDataTemplates`/`DataTemplates` for different types, each containing a `ContentControl` with a specific `Template`, like so:

```
TreeView
|- HierarchicalDataTemplate for Type a
|  |- ContentControl
|
|- DataTemplate for Type b
   |- ContentControl
```

The type `b` is built like this:

```
b
|-integer c
|-object d
```

`d` can be anything from an integer to a string, but it can also be a class containing a list. In that case I want to display the list of `d` using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` inside the `TreeView` described above.

Is there a way to do that, or do I lose all connection to the hierarchy of the `TreeView` as soon as I enter the `DataTemplate`/`ContentControl`/`Template`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex scenarios like this, you can implement a custom [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). From your description I assume a data types like these for `A` and `B`, with properties for `C` and `D`:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B
{
   public B(int c, object d)
   {
      C = c;
      D = d;
   }

   public int C { get; }

   public object D { get; }
}
```

You could create custom data templates for each type and purpose. For `B`, there would be both a `DataTemplate` for the regular types and a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for when `D` is a collection:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:CustomDataTemplateSelector/>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ATemplate"
                    DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
         <TextBlock Text="This is an A."/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="BTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:B}">
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding C}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding D}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BHierarchicalTemplate"
                                DataType="{x:Type local:B}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding D}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding C}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The [`x:Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xkey-directive)s are needed to resolve to the data templates using the [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). In this case, we would check if an item is of type `A` and use the `ATemplate`. If it is `B`, we check whether its template needs to be hierarchical or not by inspecting property `D`. If it is a collection - or in more general terms an [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-7.0), we use the hierarchical template. However, be aware that some types like [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0) are enumberable, too, so we need to make a separate check.

```
public class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   private const string ATemplateName = "ATemplate";
   private const string BTemplateName = "BTemplate";
   private const string BHierarchicalTemplateName = "BHierarchicalTemplate";

   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (!(container is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
         return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

      // >= C# 6
      //switch (item)
      //{
      //   case A:
      //      return FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, ATemplateName);
      //   case B b when b.D is string:
      //      return FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BTemplateName);
      //   case B b when b.D is IEnumerable:
      //      return FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BHierarchicalTemplateName);
      //   case B:
      //      return FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BTemplateName);
      //   default:
      //      return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
      //}
      
      // >= C# 8
      return item switch
      {
         A => FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, ATemplateName),
         B { D: string } => FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BTemplateName),
         B { D: IEnumerable } => FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BHierarchicalTemplateName),
         B => FindDataTemplate(frameworkElement, BTemplateName),
         _ => base.SelectTemplate(item, container)
      };
   }

      private static DataTemplate FindDataTemplate(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, string key)
   {
      return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource(key);
   }
}
```

Whether you create constants for the template names or build the keys from the type names or expose properties to assign the data templates is up to your requirements.